# How does $3F_3 + 4F_4 + 5F_5 + ...$ relate to $E$?

Tags: geometry

could someone help me with this question. I have a basic idea of what they are asking for but have no idea of how to show/say they are related.

Let $P$ be a convex polyhedron with $V$ vertices, $E$ edges and $F$ faces.
Furthermore, let $F_m$ be the number of faces surrounded by $m$ edges,
and let $V_m$ be the number of vertices from which $m$ edges emanate.

(1) How does $3F_3 + 4F_4 + 5F_5 + ...$ relate to $E$?

(2) How does $3V_3 + 4V_4 + 5V_5 + ...$ relate to $E$?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to calculate the different numbers at least for the Platonic solids? How about the Archimedean ones? The pattern should become apparent before you get that far though.

Comment: Cut your polyhedron up into separate faces by splitting each edge in two. Now you have just a collection of unrelated planar polygons. How many edges are in this collection?. How does that number relate to the number of edges in the original polyhedron?. For the vertices, go back to the original polyhedron. Cut each edge in two, so now you just have a collection of "spiky points". How many spikes are in this collection? and how does that number relate to the number of edges in the polyhedron?